# Python pandas memory error

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I'm trying to convert data in a csv file into a matrix, and this is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=[0,1,2], names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns='B', values='C')
```

So the input is something like this:

```
1 1 1.0 3
1 2 2.0 4
1 3 3.2 4
1 4 2.3 5
1 5 1.3 2
2 1 2.2 5
2 2 3.2 5
2 3 2.2 4
2 4 1.1 4
```

and the output is this:

```
1    2   3    4    5
1  1.0  2.0  3.2  2.3 1.3
2  2.2   5   3.2  1.1  . 
3   .    .     .   .   .
```

However, this pandas pivot table appears to only work for smaller csv files, and if I applied it to a larger csv file, there's a memory error. Not sure if it's Jupyter that's the problem, but here's the error code:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-46167ab8fec6> in <module>()
       1 import pandas as pd
 ----> 2 df = pd.read_csv('largercsv.csv', usecols=[0,1,2], names=['A', 'B', 'C'], skiprows=25)
       3 pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns='B', values='C')


     643                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
     644 
 --> 645         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
     646 
     647     parser_f.__name__ = name


     398         return parser
     399 
 --> 400     data = parser.read()
     401     parser.close()
     402     return data


     937 
 --> 938         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
     939 
     940         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):


    1505     def read(self, nrows=None):
    1506         try:
 -> 1507             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
    1508         except StopIteration:
    1509             if self._first_chunk:

     pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:10364)()

     pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:11065)()

     pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser._concatenate_chunks (pandas\parser.c:27499)()

     MemoryError:
```

Could be my computer speed, but not exactly sure how to go about it.
Also, I've been looking around but was unable to convert the output into an excel spreadsheet. Any way to go around these issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How large is 'largercsv.csv'?

Comment: It's around 800-850mB

Comment: Doesn't seem like a lot. How much RAM are you working with?

Comment: I have 8.0G of RAM

Comment: `df.as_matrix()` converts pandas df to numpy array.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, as long as it returns the same output as above.